# ASP.NET JSON & Webmethod

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I send a value with JSON from the client to the code behind in ASP.NET.

Everything is working. But if I want to use the variable in the code behind, I have no access to it.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class TextExample
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim lala As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub AddTimeToList(myJsonData As String)
        Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer()

        Dim myTime As String = json.Deserialize(Of String)(myJsonData)

        lala = myTime
    End Sub
End Class
```

`myTime` is the value I get from the client via JSON, `lala` is the variable defined on top.

Error Code:
     Error 3 Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class

JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TextExample.aspx/AddTimeToList",
                    data: "{'myJsonData':'" + JSON.stringify(timer.innerHTML) + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
```

Comment: @Kabulan0lak you might have indented correctly, but you re-broke everything else...

Comment: what do you mean by **no access** to it?

Comment: When I run my Webapplication I get an error in the line lala = myTime.

Error: Error 3 Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, but I re-broke what ? I didn't mean to.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak the other changes I'd made. When you edit a post, try to fix everything you can; have a look at my edit for an example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I edited nothing was modified yet I think. Maybe we edited at the same moment. But thanks for the advice I am quite new to editing questions.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot access instance variables in a static method. your webmethod is static/shared but your lala variable is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem.

I created a List and saved it to a session variable.

```
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Sub AddTimeToList(myJsonData As String)
    Dim myJson As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim myTime As String = myJson.Deserialize(Of String)(myJsonData)

    HttpContext.Current.Session("mySession") = myTime
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are trying to access a instance value from a shared method, and that is forbidden.

You need to declare the web method as a not shared :

```
Public Sub AddTimeToList(myJsonData As String)
```

Comment: That's what I did but what I want is for example to add the value to a Label like this:

Label1.Text = myTime

Comment: That was, in fact, the other way around ; you needs to not declare the method as shared. I will edit the answser

Comment: If I do that I have no more access from javascript (json) to the method. I added my javascript code to my first post.

Comment: I am not familiar with this version of ASP.NET, but it looks like a WebMethod is usually used on a WebService page instead of an UI.Page. I can't do more to help you, unfortunately.